# understanding pushState with different URL's

Tags: html, pushstate

I'm looking at [this](http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/whiskers) website

and I'm trying to figure out how I could go about doing something like that, but with different pages. Because what I see is:

```
 fluffy: {
            content: 'Fluffy!',
            photo: 'http://placekitten.com/200/200'
          },
          socks: {
            content: 'Socks!',
            photo: 'http://placekitten.com/280/280'
          },
          whiskers: {
            content: 'Whiskers!',
            photo: 'http://placekitten.com/350/350'
          },
          bob: {
            content: 'Just Bob.',
            photo: 'http://placekitten.com/320/270'
          }
```

and that's for different pages. But I wanted to know if it was possible to have individual pages like `home.php` or `links.php`? rather than content inside the parameters of

```
 bob: {
                content: 'Just Bob.',
                photo: 'http://placekitten.com/320/270'
              }
```

Comment: not sure what you're asking...could you be more clear?

Comment: trying to find something simple to where I can manage content on my website without having to update each individual page for the navigation. So If I have a navigation, I can just go in and edit that one particular page, rather than each page with the navigation on it. So Navigation then content in the middle. But that content would be a div (where all pages link to that div)